# Microsoft , Hotmail , Live , MSN, Outlook , unable to send emails and no support received from microsoft in 3 months we are trying asking for that

Tags: ip, outlook, blacklist, email

Ok this is somenthing unbelievable, we have a website, users sign up and receives links to confirm they signed up BUT:

```
 1 - microsoft blocked our IP (no one with microsoft email account can receive our emails)
 2 - we tryed contacting microsoft submitting the detailed form about our problem
 3 - we posted 3 times in their community about our problem
 4 - we tweeted they about our problem
 5 - we tryed finding out some telephone support number (the few there are arent' helping at all)
```

Do you think we solved?  the answer is `NO` :/

We still unable to send emails from our IP to [microsoft](http://microsoft.com) email accounts, since 3 months back.

Our emails are perfect we checked all the email headers following microsoft guidelines  but it seems not enought, checking our IP reputation it seems everythings ok, indeed we can send email easly to any other provider , gmail, yahoo, etc

Do you know any other way to try to get help ?

FULL STACK ERROR FROM MICROSOFT:

```
 host mx1.hotmail.com[65.55.37.120] said: 550
    SC-001 (COL0-MC4-F28) Unfortunately, messages from 94.23.***** weren't
    sent. Please contact your Internet service provider since part of their
    network is on our block list. You can also refer your provider to
    http://mail.live.com/mail/troubleshooting.aspx#errors. (in reply to MAIL
    FROM command)
```

We are running a Virtual Private Server , so no HOSTING SITE, using NGINX too

Comment: The ip address you're sending email from is within a netblock of ip addresses that they have blocked. They have no requirement to unblock it. It's unfortunate, but that's the way it is. There's probably nothing you can do short of moving your services to a provider that isn't blocked.

Comment: @joeqwerty no please guys you can't suggest to move an envoirment everytime you get blocked :D , come on ;) I'm not a genius but i learned that IP needs time to get reputation, if i move to another IP that will need more time :D

Comment: 1. ip addresses don't build reputation. 2. If an email provider chooses to block your ip address they can block it for any reason they want. There is no standard practice nor governing body that mandates why an ip address will be blocked. Many email providers block ip addresses and ip address blocks that are known to be the source of spam or that are allocated dynamically to end users (ISP allocates you an ip address from their block for your DSL\Cable internet etc.).

Comment: What I'm saying is that there's no way for you or anyone else to make Microsoft remove your ip address from their block list and if it's important to you to send email to them then the easiest course of action would be to move your services to a provider that isn't on the block list.

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft ban whole /24 IP ranges they do not usually block a single IP, as a service provider I can tell you that it is near impossible to get MS to budge on such problems even more so when other people in the same IP range as you could be sending spam or poorly constructed emails from badly configured servers.

The best solution to this is to pipe your emails through another IP/service such as authsmtp or alter things on your site so that any emails going to a hotmail email address come from a hotmail email address.

Also keep in mind that if your website is just a standard hosting package you are sharing the IP with 100's if not 1000's of others who could be hurting your chances, to be blunt, Microsoft don't care about your site and no amount of complaining will make them care, if email delivery is vital for you find an assured method of delivery instead.

Comment: error is returned by the Microsoft DAEMON, they are blocking us i'll post the full error stack, check my answer i updated ;)

Comment: thank you for the tips, what i mean is, should i really set an hotmail account to send my emails so that i get banned again and again ? :/

Comment: Sure smtp services are ok, but they costs, and the principle is that my site is not sending SPAM so i don't want to get blocked, but you know , it's all about microsoft :/

Comment: Based on your update I can tell you that you will probably never be able to deliver email to hotmail from your IP, the reputation must be VERY low for your IP range for them to outight reject rather than let the MS SmartFilter do its job.

I would suggest that they do not have any specific issues with your site/domain so either moving your hosting or using a hotmail account may help.

Comment: no man, lol sorry but this is ridicoulous, so each time you get blocked you keep moving your site to different IP or hosting? unbelievable, IP needs time to get his reputation, the more time your reputation on that IP is good the less troubles you'll get in future i can't image me changing hosting each 3 weeks really :D

Comment: i mean, searching on web i found many people getting IP unblocked , just me i'm not lucky i guess , what a sh*t microsoft is unbelievable :D

Comment: and osrry for my english ;)

Comment: The problem as I said may not be your IP they block a whole range at a time it could be anyone in your IP range causing the problem which s not something you can fix. you think hotmail is bad wait until you get a gmail block...